# accessing method in module of module ruby

Tags: ruby, module

I'm trying to modify existing ruby code, and ruby is not my first languange. Part of the code is like below:

```
#someFile1.rb
module A
  module B
    def somefunction()
    end
  end
end

class X::Y
  include A::B
end


#someFile2.rb    
module A
  module C
    def anotherfunction()
      #somefunction() <-- error
    end
  end
end
class X::Y
  include A::C
end
```

Somehow I can't access method `somefunction()` in `anotherfunction`.
How to access method defined in module B in method inside module C? Why it's not working?

Comment: The situation is not clear. You need to add more to make it clear.

Comment: @sawa I've updated the question, is it still unclear?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instance methods in modules aren't generally accessible until you mix them into a class and create an object of that class.

```
module A
  module B
    def some_method
      "foo"
    end 
  end
end 

module A
  module C
    def another_method
      some_method
    end 
  end
end 

class X 
  include A::B
  include A::C
end

X.new.another_method
# => "foo"
```

But I'd say it isn't very elegant to have a module that depends upon the fact that some other module has also been mixed into the same object

Class methods in modules, on the other hand, are accessible like this:

```
module A
  module B
    def self.somefunction
      "foo"
    end 
  end
end 

module A
  module C
    def self.another_function
      A::B.somefunction
    end 
  end
end 

A::C.another_function
# => "foo"
```

Comment: Thanks for answering, I've updated my question. I also tried to include both module B and C inside class X, but to no avail. The error is `Uninitialized constant A::B` Any idea why?

Comment: It sounds like you haven't required the file that contains `A::B`. The reason that the code in your updated question doesn't work is that you don't include `A::B` so the method isn't present in `X`.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want to call the module functions themselves, you would first need to make them module functions (think `static` in Java or `namespace` in C++). Then you can use the `::` (namespace resolution) operator. See `foo` and `bar`.

If you want to import them into classes, just import both, and both will be visible. See `baz` and `qux`.

```
module A
  module B
    def self.foo
      puts "foo"
    end

    def baz
      puts "baz"
    end
  end
end

module A
  module C
    def self.bar
      puts "bar"
      A::B::foo
    end

    def qux
      puts "qux"
      baz
    end
  end
end

class X
  include A::B
  include A::C
end

A::C::bar

x = X.new
x.qux
```

Output:

```
bar
foo
baz
qux
```